# Use of 'of' and 'none' in the following sentence

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

> Cows are amongst the gentlest **of** animals; **none** shows more passionate tenderness towards their young.

In this sentence, why there is '**of**' after '*the gentlest*' and the use of **none** is also confused me. Suggest any other term which could be used in place of **none**.

Comment: **No other animal**.

Answer (score 2):

It is a formal structure that is commonly used. [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/superlative-adjectives_10) explains:

> *The superlative adjective* [in your case ***gentlest***] comes after ***the*** and is *followed by a prepositional phrase which consists of **of** and a plural noun group* [in your case ***animals***]. The adjective is sometimes followed by ***among*** instead of ***of***.
>
> *When the preposition is followed by a noun only, the noun indicates **a type of person or thing**.* A phrase such as *the richest **of** families* is similar in meaning to *the richest families*.
>
> > My school friends were all dressed up and all came from ***the best and richest of families***.
> > He has never enjoyed a reputation as ***the most tactful of politicians***.

So you can understand your sentence as

> Cows are amongst the gentlest [animals] of [the whole group of] animals.
> *<sup>(In this group of animals, there is a sub-group formed by the gentlest animals. Cows belong to this sub-group.)</sup>*

---

As for ***none***, you can replace it by ***no other animal***, as @Kate suggested. You could also rewrite the sentence as:

> ***No animal*** shows more passionate tenderness towards their young ***than them/than cows***.

This version however is more wordy, more repetitive. Now, some may argue that ***show*** should be in the plural because here ***none*** stands for ***none of the animals***, but some dictionaries and grammar sites say it depends on what you want to stress, the plurality of the group or the uniqueness of *not one*. See for example [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/none/) and [ProofreadNow](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/57554/NONE-Is-it-singular-or-plural).

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/video/is-none-singular-or-plural#:%7E:text=Usage%20experts%20acknowledge%20that%20none,when%20it%20means%20not%20any.) summarises the issue in this way:

> Usage experts acknowledge that none is sometimes singular and sometimes plural. They mostly recommend that you treat it as ***singular*** when it means *not one*, or *no amount*, and ***plural*** when it means *not any*.